# CSS Smooth Scroll Stop

Tags: css, scroll, web-deployment

I want the behavior that when I stop scrolling , the scrolling should stop after
scrolling a little bit slowly and not immediately
Help me to implement this behavior.

[example website](https://abhishekjha.me/)

Answer (score -1):

this will be useful

```
html,body {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Comment: This only affects browser behaviour when using links to jump to an anchor elsewhere on the same page. It doesn't change browser behaviour when the user is scrolling manually - which is what the questioner is asking about.

Comment: @akarnokd: Why not? It may not be a _correct_ answer, but surely it's _an_ answer.

Comment: @JeremyCaney system flagged this as low quality answer and it appears so. Also it sounds as a self reminder which all in all should have been a comment.

Comment: @akarnokd: Oh, it’s definitely low quality. (I also came across it via the _LQA_ queue.) And it would be a better answer with an explanation. But it should be downvoted for that, not deleted, since it still offers a potential solution ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue).) Deleting is for answers that make no attempt to answer the question, such as new questions, follow-up questions, clarifications of other answers, link-only answers, &c. It isn’t meant for short, code-only, or speculative answers.

Comment: Alright, retracted my vote.